# Put a layout in an image view

Tags: android, imageview

I have a Relative Layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/follow_icon_circle">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_width="13dp"
    android:layout_height="13dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/follow_button_plus_icon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_follow_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/plus"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/plus"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/tab_menu_selected_color"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to put this layout in an image view.
Like this: imageView1.setImageResource(R.layout.RelativeLayout);

But it is not working.
How can I put this appearance in my imageView?

Comment: its not possible, ImageViews are for displaying images, Try using LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, it supports nesting

Comment: `ImageView` does not extend `ViewGroup`... also `setImageResource` takes an `R.drawable`, **not** an `R.layout`

Comment: If you want to show **image** of elements,  you need to draw them by using `draw` method of `android.view.View` class on canvas, created from `Bitmap` and use it as content in `ImageView`.

Comment: It is very complex for me, I'm afraid that is impossible that way. I have to find another algorithm. @VallyN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name an id for the layout you want to get as an Image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:background="@drawable/follow_icon_circle">
```

And you need to create a bitmap like below..

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
relativeLayout.draw(canvas);
```

And set it to your imageview.

```
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```